# Controlador laravel no hace update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel

Tengo un problema cuando intento hacer el update de la información, al presionar el btn para editar la información carga una vista con los campos de texto mismos que obtienen informacion de la tabla, pero cuando los edito y trato de hacer submit salen los errores del request, por ejemplo en el atributo **ruc** tengo definido en el request como `required|numeric|max:13` y al hacer submit al formulario con los datos ya ingresados , aparece en pantalla que el campo debe ser ingresado o que debe ser numérico, es decir es como que si mi formulario enviara los campos varios y saltan las alertas. incluso si no edito la información de la tabla y realizo el submit con la misma información igual saltan las alertas.

**Tabla que pretendo actualizar**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esto es lo que muestra al actualizar**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para llegar a esa vista presiono el botón editar que se encuentra en el **index** este es el código.

```
<a href="/info_junta/{{$i->idjunta}}/edit" class="btn btn-success"><li class="fa fa-edit"></li>&nbsp; Editar información</a>
```

**Controlador**

```
<?php

namespace juntaAgua\Http\Controllers;

use juntaAgua\InfoJunta;
use juntaAgua\Http\Requests\InfoJuntaRequest;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use juntaAgua\Http\Requests;
use DB;

use Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class MantenimientoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {


        if ($request) {
            $query = DB::table('junta')
                ->where('idjunta', '=', '1')
                ->get();
            return view('mantenimiento.info_junta', ["infoJunta" => $query]);
        } else {
            return 'No existe informacion referente a la Junta';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('mantenimiento.edit_junta', ["infoJunta" => InfoJunta::findOrFail($id)]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(InfoJuntaRequest $request, $id)
    {



        $infoJunta = InfoJunta::findOrFail($id);
        $infoJunta->nombre = $request->get('nombre');
        $infoJunta->mision = $request->get('mision');
        $infoJunta->vision = $request->get('vision');
        $infoJunta->ruc = $request->get('ruc');
        $infoJunta->logo = $request->get('logo');
        $infoJunta->update();

        return Redirect::to('/info_junta');

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        return 'intento delete!';
    }
}
```

**Request**

```
<?php

namespace juntaAgua\Http\Requests;

use juntaAgua\Http\Requests\Request;

class InfoJuntaRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nombre'=>'required|max:100',
            'info'=>'max:500',
            'logo'=>'max:100',
            'ruc'=>'required|max:13|numeric',
            'mision'=>'max:500',
            'vision'=>'max:500'
        ];
    }
}
```

**Formulario para la edición**

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('contenido')
    <div id="lol">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Datos informativos de la Junta Administradora de Agua</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @if(count($errors)>0)
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{$error}}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="row">
                            {!!Form::model($infoJunta,['method'=>'patch','route'=>['info_junta.destroy',$infoJunta->idjunta]])!!}
                            {{Form::token()}}
                            <div class="form-group has-success">

                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="">IdJunta</label>
                                    <input disabled type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$infoJunta->idjunta}}">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <label for="">Ruc</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="ruc" value="{{$infoJunta->ruc}}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <label for="">Nombre de la Junta</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre"
                                           value="{{$infoJunta->nombre}}">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="">Misión</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="mision" id="" cols="30"
                                          rows="10">{{$infoJunta->mision}}</textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <label for="">Visión</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="vision" id="" cols="30"
                                          rows="10">{{$infoJunta->vision}}</textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <label for="">Foto</label>
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="foto" value="{{$infoJunta->logo}}">
                                </div>

                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                            <li class="fa fa-save"></li>
                            &nbsp;Actualizar
                        </button>
                        {!!Form::close()!!}
                        <a href="/info_junta" class="btn btn-default"><li class="fa fa-times"></li>&nbsp;Cancelar</a>



                    </div>




                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>








@endsection
```

**Route.php**

```
Route::resource('/info_junta','MantenimientoController');
```

**php artisan route:list**

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | info_junta/create                | info_junta.create        | juntaAgua\Http\Controllers\MantenimientoController@create      | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | info_junta/{info_junta}          | info_junta.show          | juntaAgua\Http\Controllers\MantenimientoController@show        | web        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | info_junta/{info_junta}          | info_junta.update        | juntaAgua\Http\Controllers\MantenimientoController@update      | web        |
|        | DELETE    | info_junta/{info_junta}          | info_junta.destroy       | juntaAgua\Http\Controllers\MantenimientoController@destroy     | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | info_junta/{info_junta}/edit     | info_junta.edit          | juntaAgua\Http\Controllers\MantenimientoController@edit        | web        |
```

Comment: Aparentemente no tiene nada que ver, pero veo que la ruta del formulario es `'route'=>['info_junta.destroy'` y debería ser `info_junta.update`, ¿o estoy viendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que estás usando mal la validación de `max:13`. Tal y como lo dice la documentación esta regla valida un número específico, no la longitud del campo, en enteros.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-size

> El número 1800567323 es mayor que 13.

---

Si lo que quieres es validar la cantidad de dígitos, puedes usar `digits:13` si el número siempre tiene 13 dígitos, o `digits_between:1,13` asumiendo que se permitan entre 1 y 13 dígitos.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-digits

Comment: Estimado amigo gracias por tu comentario, ya cambie en request de la siguiente `'nombre'=>'required|digits_between:1,100'` según entendí de esta forma poder ingresar de entre 1 a 100 dígitos, ya que en mi tabla el campo nombre es un varchar de 100, pero ahora sale lo siguiente `El campo nombre debe contener entre 1 y 100 dígitos. ` :(

Comment: Lo estás aplicando mal, esa validación es para el campo `ruc`.

Answer (score 0):

Estás aplicando mal la validación.
Dices que 'nombre' es de tipo varchar(100), entonces debes de validar un string y no un numero.

```
        'Nombre' => 'required|string|min:1|max:100'
```

De esa forma dices que el campo Nombre es requerido, es de tipo string y puede tener un mínimo de 1 y un máximo de 100.